# Can't reboot Intel Atom x5-Z8350 running Ubuntu Server 20.04/21.10 – kernel soft lockup

Tags: ubuntu, shutdown, reboot, atom

I'm unable to completely shutdown my system after running `sudo init 6` or `sudo shutdown -reboot`

[This](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09KLDPGP9) is the system I have,
which runs on the Atom x5-Z8350 Cherry Trail CPU. 
Previously I installed 20.04 I saw an error while rebooting
– part of that error was:

> an error BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 22s!

Unfortunately I'm not sure where I could have found the entire log file,
and now I've installed 21.10.

I thought the kernel on 21.10 would have solved my issue. 
Things looked well since the verbose was giving me back "[ok]" for everything. 
Unfortunately, there were no errors shown on the display, and my display turns off but the system and keyboard stay on, and I'm forced to hold the shutdown button.

What commands should I run that could help you guys better understand my hardware plus how can I log or find the logs for the failed reboot?

AFAIK errors for reboot/shutdown are not saved since the system dismounts.

```
watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 26s! [shutdown:1]
watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 54s! [shutdown:1]
watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 104s! [shutdown:1]
[drm:drm_crtc_commit_wait [drm]] *ERROR* flip_done timed out
[drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:93:pipe C] commit wait timed out
[drm:drm_crtc_commit_wait [drm]] *ERROR* flip_done timed out
[drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CONNECTOR:107:HDMI-A-2] commit wait timed out
watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 131s! [shutdown:1]
[drm:drm_crtc_commit_wait [drm]] *ERROR* flip_done timed out
[drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [PLANE:73:primary C] commit wait timed out
[drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_flip_done [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:93:pipe C] flip_done wait timed out
watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 157s! [shutdown:1]
watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 183s! [shutdown:1]
watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 209s! [shutdown:1]
watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 235s! [shutdown:1]
rcu: INFO: rcu_sched self-detected stall on CPU
rcu: ‡1-....: (65719 ticks this GP) idle=9be/1/0x4000000000000000 softirq=9335/9336 fqs=29997 
watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 272s! [shutdown:1]
watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 298s! [shutdown:1]
watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 324s! [shutdown:1]
watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 350s! [shutdown:1]
watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 376s! [shutdown:1]
watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 402s! [shutdown:1]
rcu: INFO: rcu_sched self-detected stall on CPU
rcu: ‡1-....: (110715 ticks this GP) idle=9be/1/0x4000000000000000 softirq=9335/9336 fqs=52497
```

[[screen image of the above]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X83fg.jpg)